# Manipulate a plot of coupled differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

Good afternoon,

I am attempting to construct a graph showing the trajectory of two variables over time, based on a coupled system of differential equations and some arbitrary initial conditions which I'll invariably end up changing later.

The model comes from a Latent Differential Equation model, a form of Structural Equation Modelling. A picture of the structural model I'm trying to build is attached below. From it, a coupled system of differential equations can be formed. I'm trying to plot a graph so I can show the behaviour over time based on different coefficients. As such, I'm trying to make a diagram which enables me to manipulate these coefficients. The bulk of my code is below:

```
sol[etax_, zetax_, gammay_, gammaydot_, etay_, zetay_, gammax_, gammaxdot_] := NDSolve[{
x''[t] - etax*x[t] - zetax*x'[t] - gammay*y[t] - gammaydot*y'[t] == 0,
y''[t] - etay*y[t] - zetay*y'[t] - gammax*x[t] - gammaxdot*x'[t] == 0,
x[0] == 0.1,
x'[0] == 0.1,
y[0] == 0.1,
y'[0] == 0.1},
y, {x, 0, 10}]
Manipulate[
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol[etax, zetax, gammay, gammaydot, etay, zetay, gammax, 
gammaxdot]], {x, 0, 10},PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-10, 10}}],
{{etax, 1, "etax"}, -3, 3, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
```

When attempting this, I get a large list of warning messages. I am a little new to the Mathematica/Differential Equations circuit so have probably made a rookie error somewhere, but would really appreciate if anyone could offer any corrections or recommendations which help me with this model building.

Many thanks,

[image: Structural Model Diagram]

Comment: Best to supply all of the minimal amount of code the replicates the issue.

Comment: A couple of observations: (1): Within the `NDSolve` in your `sol` function, I think you want`==` (Equal, returns True if lhs and rhs are identical) rather than `=`(Set).  (2) The NDSolve does not specify a domain for `t`, again, I think you want something, e.g., like `{x, 0, 10}, {t, 20}` at the end of the `NDSolve` using whatever appropriate values you need for `t`. I don't see much else one can do to help without more of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NDSolve` code is not valid: you should solve for the unknown functions `x` and `y` for a range `{t,0,tmax}`. After fixing this issue `sol` works. You can then incorparate the method into a `Manipulate` function e.g.:

```
sol[etax_,zetax_,gammay_,gammaydot_,etay_,zetay_,gammax_,gammaxdot_,tmax_]:=NDSolve[{x''[t]-etax*x[t]-zetax*x'[t]-gammay*y[t]-gammaydot*y'[t]==0,y''[t]-etay*y[t]-zetay*y'[t]-gammax*x[t]-gammaxdot*x'[t]==0,x[0]==0.1,x'[0]==0.1,y[0]==0.1,y'[0]==0.1},{x[t],y[t]},{t,0,tmax}]
Manipulate[With[{res={x[t],y[t]}/.First[sol[etax,zetax,gammay,gammaydot,etay,zetay,gammax,gammaxdot,3]]},ParametricPlot[res,{t,0,3},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"x","y"}]],{{etax,1,"etax"},-4,4},{{zetax,1,"zetax"},-4,4},{{gammay,1,"gammay"},-4,4},{{gammaydot,-1,"gammaydot"},-4,4},{{etay,1,"etay"},-4,4},{{zetay,1,"zetay"},-4,4},{{gammax,1,"gammax"},-4,4},{{gammaxdot,-2,"gammaxdot"},-4,4}]
```

[image: Parametric plot]

You could use a similar approach to using `Plot` to plot the `x` and `y` component over `t` instead of the using `ParametricPlot` or you could use `ParametricPlot3D` to plot `x`, `y` and `t` simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback on this, the diagram works perfectly now. A 3D plot would probably better demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve, so I will adjust the code to create that. Thank you for the suggestion too.